# HTML encode all input in ASP.NET MVC 2 site by default

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc, security, asp.net-mvc-2

Good day!

I'd like to html encode all user input on the ASP.NET MVC 2 site but default. Can this be done anywhere on model binder level?

If I disable input validation for action -- I will need to html-encode every other value. If I keep ASP.NET request validation on -- it will throw erros "A potentially dangerous Request.Form value was detected from the client"

P.S. I do use encoding when outputting data (<%: %> syntax), but I'd like to encode everything on posting it too.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Why? To just work around the 'potentially dangerous' error? That's the wrong way to do this - just disable that error if you're confident it's not needed. You'd need to do the encode in JavaScript before you submit the form and you can't rely on the client to run that script.

Comment: No, I'd like to perform HTML encoding by default on server for all my fields (and selectively allow it for some fields). The reason is that user can try to post HTML and he shouldn't get an error -- it will be better if he sees that HTML was encoded.

Comment: HTML encoding everything on the server makes absolutely non sense whatsoever. Don't do it, please. Use `<%: %>` or `<%= Html.DisplayFor(x => x.Foo) %>` and be happy.

Comment: Why do you want to encode user *input*? You need to encode the *output*.

Comment: encoring input is the best way .because once it is  in database in encoded format we don't want to worry whenever it is outputted

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Unfortunately XSS is an output problem,  not an input problem.  Running everything though an HTML encoder will not solve all your problems.    There are [many ways of obtaining xss](http://ha.ckers.org/xss.html) without `<>`.

In general input should be validated just before use.  You cannot predict how all input will be used,  and you will end up corrupting data.

Answer (score 0):

You can override the `DefaultModelBinder`.

Comment: P.S. I don't know why you want to do this, but it is certainly possible